# Angular.js routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey guys ive been trying to use routing, still new to angular though :( I have the first page already made, but am trying to make it when you click enter the next page appears on top of the current page (so basically a new page). The reason I want it to be all 1 page is so I can transfer the data from the first page onto the second page, however I can't seem to get it to load the next page... Here's my html and js so far,, not sure where im going wrong -_-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/kandi.css">
</head>
<body data-ng-app="nameBox" class="ng-scope">
    <ng-view></ng-view> 
    <section class="frontPageBox">
        <div  data-ng-controller="appearCntrl">
            <form action="" method="">          
                <input type="text" data-ng-bind="name" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Your Name..." id="name-input">
                <a type="button" class="button" href="#/kandi2" style="text-decoration:none;color:#ccc;">Enter</a>              
            </form>
            <p style="color:#999; font-size: 1.1em;">{{"Welcome " + name}}</p>
        </div>

    </section>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("nameBox", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when("/kandi2", {
                    templateUrl : "kandi2.html"
                });
            });
        app.controller("appearCntrl", function($scope){
            $scope.name = "";
            $scope.data = [];
            $scope.data.push(name);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: can you please fiddle it out?

Comment: I think Using Factory through you can easily pass data in any controller.

Comment: no errors in console... here is the fiddle.. for some reason in the fiddle none of the angular works 
https://jsfiddle.net/0dLha73v/ i must be missing something

Comment: @AranS just checked it again on a different computer, this is the errors I am getting. 

Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

angular.js:12520Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$compile/tpload?p0=kandi2.html&p1=-1&p2=
    at Error (native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the ng-view tag

```
  <ng-view></ng-view>
```

Gives an `<!-- ngView: undefined -->` element in the DOM, there is no place to attach the view.

You could write something like:

```
  <div ng-view></div>
```

Then it should work.

Comment: when I use <div ng-view></div>.. and I click the button to load the next page, it shows in the address bar that the next page has been clicked, but nothing loads..

Comment: I copied your code into my solution, and it works for me but only when I did the above.The only thing that really can differ is the templateUrl. Is "kandi2.html" a valid path? You can use the browsers nerwork tab to confirm.

Comment: the html is valid, I even tried it with different html... do I need to be on a server for it to work?? or did you just copy paste into a file and it worked?

Comment: I have got it working now, ran it through xampp on another computer, thank you so much for the help :D